# Multiple foreign keys?

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys

I've got a table that is supposed to track days and costs for shipping product from one vendor to another. We (brilliantly :p) stored both the shipping vendors (FedEx, UPS) with the product handling vendors (Think... Dunder Mifflin) in a "VENDOR" table. So, I have three columns in my SHIPPING_DETAILS table that all reference VENDOR.no. For some reason MySQL isn't letting me define all three as foreign keys. Any ideas?

```
CREATE TABLE SHIPPING_GRID(  
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'Unique ID for each row',  
    shipping_vendor_no INT(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign key to VENDOR.no for the shipping vendor (vendors_type must be 3)',  
    start_vendor_no INT(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign key to VENDOR.no for the vendor being shipped from',  
    end_vendor_no INT(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign key to the VENDOR.no for the vendor being shipped to',  
    shipment_duration INT(1) DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Duration in whole days shipment will take',  
    price FLOAT(5,5) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Price in US dollars per shipment lbs (down to 5 decimal places)',  
    is_flat_rate TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '1 if is flat rate regardless of weight, 0 if price is by lbs',  
    INDEX (shipping_vendor_no),  
    INDEX (start_vendor_no),  
    INDEX (end_vendor_no),  
    FOREIGN KEY (shipping_vendor_no) REFERENCES VENDOR (no),  
    FOREIGN KEY (start_vendor_no) REFERENCES VENDOR (no),  
    FOREIGN KEY (end_vendor_no) REFERENCES VENDOR (no)  
) TYPE = INNODB;
```

*Edited to remove double primary key definition...*

---

Yeah, unfortunately that didn't fix it though. Now I'm getting:

> Can't create table
>   './*REMOVED MY DB NAME*/SHIPPING_GRID.frm'
>   (errno: 150)

Doing a phpinfo() tells me this for mysql:

> Client API version    5.0.45

Yes, the VENDOR.no is type int(6).

Comment: Indeed, error 150 refers to a [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) error. Can you provide the definition of the VENDOR table? Is the PK of VENDOR an INT(6) or just an INT? From the above page: - *The size and sign of integer types must be the same.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You defined the primary key twice. Try:

```
CREATE TABLE SHIPPING_GRID(  
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'Unique ID for each row',  
    shipping_vendor_no INT(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign key to VENDOR.no for the shipping vendor (vendors_type must be 3)',  
    start_vendor_no INT(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign key to VENDOR.no for the vendor being shipped from',  
    end_vendor_no INT(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign key to the VENDOR.no for the vendor being shipped to',  
    shipment_duration INT(1) DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Duration in whole days shipment will take',  
    price FLOAT(5,5) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Price in US dollars per shipment lbs (down to 5 decimal places)',  
    is_flat_rate TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '1 if is flat rate regardless of weight, 0 if price is by lbs',  
    INDEX (shipping_vendor_no),  
    INDEX (start_vendor_no),  
    INDEX (end_vendor_no),  
    FOREIGN KEY (shipping_vendor_no) REFERENCES VENDOR (no),  
    FOREIGN KEY (start_vendor_no) REFERENCES VENDOR (no),  
    FOREIGN KEY (end_vendor_no) REFERENCES VENDOR (no)  
) TYPE = INNODB;
```

The VENDOR primary key must be INT(6), and both tables must be of type InnoDB.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you provide the definition of the
>   VENDOR table

I figured it out. The VENDOR table was MyISAM... (edited your answer to tell me to make them both INNODB ;) )

(any reason *not* to just switch the VENDOR type over to INNODB?)

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code here, and the error message showed (and it is right!) that you are setting *id* field twice as primary key.