# How do I update a table that only has foreign keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a database with a table with only foreign keys. I am able to manually add data into this table, and then remove it with code. However, I am unable to add data to it. This may be because I don't actually know how to access my table, or I'm doing it wrong. Help is appreciated.

My foreign key only table:

```
CREATE TABLE UserCategory 
(
    CatID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Category(ID),
    UserID NVARCHAR(128) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [User](ID),
    CONSTRAINT PK_UserCategory PRIMARY KEY (CatID, UserID)
);
```

The code that links it in the model:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Users)
                .WithMany(e => e.Categories)
                .Map(m => m.ToTable("UserCategory").MapLeftKey("CatID").MapRightKey("UserID"));
```

As you can see, I have a table called what I created, and with the values expected.

[image]

However, when I try to access this table through code, I cannot access those values directly. I can delete values like this:

```
var userCats = thisUser.Categories.ToList();

foreach (var cat in userCats)
{
    thisUser.Categories.Remove(cat);
}
```

But when I try and access the `UserCategories` properties, I get this:

[image]

What can I do to add new `UserCategories` to my database? If I just create a new `Category`, and add that the same way I delete one (but with `Add`, obviously) I am required to fill out `Name`. Then when I fill out `Name`, it tells me there's a key conflict, because it appears to be adding it to the `Category` table, not the `UserCategory`.

Here are the other two tables in question:

```
CREATE TABLE [User] 
(
    ID NVARCHAR(128) PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(255),
    JoinDate DATETIME,
    ZipCode VARCHAR(25),
    SearchRadius INT,
    LoginToBusinessSide BIT
);

/*The categories businesses can fall under. */
CREATE TABLE Category 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
);
```

Am I trying to access it wrong? How can I access it correctly? Thank you.

Comment: In order to add to `UserCategory` you will need to add a record to `User`, get its `ID` and add a record to `Category`, get its `ID`.  Once you have those two IDs you can insert into `UserCategory` with those IDs.

Comment: @user212514 Could you show me in code how to do that? I've been struggling with this problem for such a long time, I would very much appreciate the help.

Comment: I would suggest focusing on SQL only as you study the concepts.  After you feel like you have a good handle, then layer on the C# code.  Here's a SQL example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580619/how-to-add-2-foreign-keys-in-a-table-in-a-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure why this works, but I was able to finally save entries into my UserCategory table. This is my code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < categories.Length; ++i)
{
   var user = db.Users.Find(thisUser.ID);
   var cat = db.Categories.Find(categories[i]);
   user.Categories.Add(cat);
}
```

I have to an active connection to both tables that the foreign keys are linked to, and then when I add one to the Categories table, it goes to the correct place.

If you understand exactly why this works, or if there's a better way, please do comment.